# Skipping a for loop when a condition is not met

Tags: python

I am trying to create an updated_document list from a documents list using a dictionary named ratio_dict which stores the count of all the words present in the documents and also some additional words having count 0.

I want to store all the words having value greater than 2 stored in ratio_dict. I am running the below code but it is giving me *KeyError* for all the words having count 0. I want to ignore all those words which have value stored in ratio_dict as 0. How can I give than skip condition inside that list?

```
updated_document = [[b for b in i if ratio_dict[b] >= 2.0] for i in documents]
```

For example:

```
document = [['b','m','n'],['b'],['g'],['o','b','g'],['b','g']]
ratio_dict = {'a':0, 'b':4,'c':0,'g':3,'m':1,'n':1,'o':1}
Expected updated_document = [['b','m'],['b'],['g'],['b','g'],['b','g']]
```

Comment: `[[('',b)[ratio_dict[b >= 2.0]] for b in i] for i in documents]` ?

Comment: This is not working. I am still getting KeyError.

Comment: I don't have any error, i have an output `[['b'], ['b'], ['g'], ['b', 'g'], ['b', 'g']]` because` m:1<2`. It woeks fine for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go.

`updated_document = [[b for b in i if ratio_dict.get(b, 0) >= 2.0] for i in documents]`

`ratio_dict.get(b, 0)` is used to select `b` from `ratio_dict` and in the case where `b` is not a key in `ratio_dict`, it will return `0`.

Also you might want to checkout `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Actually, I want to remove those words instead of giving them a value of 0. How will I do that.

Comment: Can you add an example input and desired output? I fail to see why this is not removing the words.